# Wrong TableView Height with 64bit Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, 32bit-64bit

I have a really strange Problem. With 64bit Devices i always geht a wrong cell height. On 32bit Devices it looks correct like this:

[image]

On Devices with 64bit Architecture, it looks like this:

[image]

This is my function, and YES i changed it from float to CGFloat after 64bit Devices got released....

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
GFBlockTableRowItem* row = [self.blockTable.tableRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

CGFloat maxHeight = 0.0f;

for (NSUInteger i=0; i<row.tableColumns.count; ++i) {
    NSString* widthValue = [self.blockTable.tableColWidths objectAtIndex:i];

    CGFloat percentage = widthValue.integerValue/100.0f;
    NSString* string = [row.tableColumns objectAtIndex:i];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*percentage, FLT_MAX);
    CGSize size = calculateSizeWithInsets(string, self.defaultCellFont, constraint, GTDefaultTableEdgeInsets);

    maxHeight = MAX(size.height, maxHeight);
}

LogDebug(@"height %li: %.3f", (long)indexPath.row, maxHeight);
return maxHeight;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GTVerticalTextAlignment) {
GTVerticalTextAlignmentTop,
GTVerticalTextAlignmentCenter,
GTVerticalTextAlignmentBottom
};

/**top, left, bottom, right*/
static UIEdgeInsets GTDefaultTableEdgeInsets = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
static UIEdgeInsets GTDefaultTextViewEdgeInsets = {8.0f, 4.0f, 8.0f, 4.0f};

CGSize calculateSizeWithInsets(NSString *text,UIFont *font, CGSize size, UIEdgeInsets insets) {
//  GT_SIZE_CONSTRAINT_NONE
CGSize constraint = size;
UIEdgeInsets effective = UIEdgeInsetsMake((insets.top + GTDefaultTextViewEdgeInsets.top),
                                          (GTDefaultTextViewEdgeInsets.left + insets.left),
                                          (insets.bottom + GTDefaultTextViewEdgeInsets.bottom),
                                          (GTDefaultTextViewEdgeInsets.right + insets.right));

if (constraint.width != GT_SIZE_CONSTRAINT_NONE) {
    constraint.width = constraint.width - (effective.left + effective.right);
}

if (constraint.height != GT_SIZE_CONSTRAINT_NONE) {
    constraint.height = constraint.height - (effective.top + effective.bottom);
}

CGSize textSize = calculateSize(text, font, constraint);

if (constraint.width == GT_SIZE_CONSTRAINT_NONE) {
    textSize.width += effective.left + effective.right;
}

if (constraint.height == GT_SIZE_CONSTRAINT_NONE) {
    textSize.height += effective.top + effective.bottom;
}

return textSize;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `FLT_MAX` instead of `CGFLOAT_MAX`?

Comment: The difficulty you're experiencing is probably to do with the fact that on a 32-bit architecture `CGFloat` is of type `float`, while on 64-bit it's `double`. Also, change `widthVlaue.integerValue` to `widthValue.floatValue`.

Comment: Now i´m using CGFLoat_MAX, it was my mistake :) I changed it to widthValue.floatValue but it didnt affect anything :/

Comment: Can you post the code of `calculateSizeWithInsets` and report the pictures please?

Answer (score 0):

In my case below method was being used

```
- (float)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

instead of this updated method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In 64 bit architecture float should be replaced with `CGFloat`.